# Processor voltage spec and motherboard socket voltage spec mismatch

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an Intel Processor E2160 [Socket LGA775, spec no. SLA9Z (CPU Voltage: 0.85V-1.5V)] Can this processor be installed on Intel DG41TY Motherboard (LGA775)?. The Processor Spec No. mentioned for this board was SLA8Z (CPU Voltage: 1.162V-1.312V) on the Intel Process match [website](http://processormatch.intel.com/compdb/). Will it affect the performance or will it not work at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your question linked to the resource you needed:

> [This combination **is fully compatible**.](http://processormatch.intel.com/compdb/SearchResult.aspx?ProcNbr=E2160&BoardName=DG41TY&Lang=en-US)

I don't think there's any reasonable way to interpret that statement as "Some revisions of the motherboard are compatible with some revisions of the CPU".

On the other hand, it does say

> Due to potential changes in products, BIOS, software, and the like, Intel is unable to warrant that the processor and boards listed above are compatible.

Comment: And further, if the voltage range the processor can handle is wider than the one the mother board will supply it, there is no problem... as Intel defines the voltage range given in processor spec like this: _"VID Voltage Range is an indicator of the minimum and maximum voltage values at which the processor is designed to operate. The processor communicates VID to the VRM (Voltage Regulator Module), which in turn delivers that correct voltage to the processor."_